# node array getting lost

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason the data in my array is getting lost at the end of a function despite it being declared outside:

```js
var resultsArray = [];
res.on('end', function() {
  var parsed = body.split('\n');

  var i;
  for ( i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++ ) {
    resultsArray.push(parsed[i].split(','));
  }

});
console.log(`\n \n---------\n${resultsArray} \n--------\n \n`);
```

This prints

---

undefined

---

but if I move the console.log statement inside the res.on function I get the array as I would expect.

Comment: It's not being lost. The callback is asynchronous and has not fired by the time you're logging to the console.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I wasn't thinking about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to use the varible inside the [**javascript callback**](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/):

```
res.on('end', function() {
  var parsed = body.split('\n');

  var i;
  for ( i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++ ) {
    resultsArray.push(parsed[i].split(','));
  }

  // Use your value from here.
  console.log(`\n \n---------\n${resultsArray} \n--------\n \n`); 
});
```

If you want to avoid [**callback hell**](http://callbackhell.com/) and write clearer code, give it a try on [**async / await**](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await).